# How to execute a PHP long time script on an a apache2 server?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache2, limit

I have a php script that inserts random data in mysql database. (approximative 1 milion rows)
Afer the script begins to run on my browser, after a few minutes (ex. 10 min or so) the script stops. (Chrome is giving me "No data recieved")

In my script I have set the followings:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time' ,0);
ini_set('set_memory_limit', '10240MB');
```

For this project I am using the Laravel framework but I don't think it has something to do with it.

Have any ideas?

Comment: Try this set_time_limit(0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It was from the framework.
For best practices I recomend:
https://laracasts.com/lessons/eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good approach to do such long running jobs via SSH (if you have SSH access to your server). Then you can execute any PHP-Script via `php your-script.php`. You just to keep two things in mind: you need to bootstrap your framework properly (if the script depends on it), and then there is also a timeout for SSH connections. You can work around this limitation by sending the running job in the background or use the `screen` command.